# iOS debug build error

Tags: codenameone

I created a new CodenameOne Project using the Hello World (Bare Bones) template and the Flat Blue theme. I have a simple one class app where the start function is:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Test Browser");
    hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    hi.setScrollable(false);
    BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
    browser.setURL("https://www.codenameone.com/");
    hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
    hi.show();
}
```

When I send the iOS debug build I get the following error:

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,19 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.createBrowserComponent(JavaSEPort.java:9025)
    at com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent.<init>(BrowserComponent.java:343)
    at com.digidava.testbrowser.TestBrowser.start(TestBrowser.java:59)
    at com.digidava.testbrowser.TestBrowserStub.run(TestBrowserStub.java:32)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1129)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:924)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
[EDT] 0:0:0,22 - Exception in TestBrowser version 1.0
[EDT] 0:0:0,23 - OS ios
[EDT] 0:0:0,23 - Error java.lang.NullPointerException
[EDT] 0:0:0,23 - Before the first form!
[EDT] 0:0:0,23 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.createBrowserComponent(JavaSEPort.java:9025)
    at com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent.<init>(BrowserComponent.java:343)
    at com.digidava.testbrowser.TestBrowser.start(TestBrowser.java:59)
    at com.digidava.testbrowser.TestBrowserStub.run(TestBrowserStub.java:32)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1129)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:924)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
[Network Thread] 0:0:1,104 - Exception: java.io.IOException - Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:338)
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:445)
    at com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:668)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.copyNoClose(Util.java:132)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.copyNoClose(Util.java:118)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.copy(Util.java:153)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.copy(Util.java:107)
    at com.codename1.io.Util.readInputStream(Util.java:202)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.readResponse(ConnectionRequest.java:1308)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:797)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Timeout reached.  Destroying process
Process timed out
Failed to generate device screenshot! /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build536155541163742895xxx/res/Default.png
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing there is a failure of the [splash screen process](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html). You shouldn't place a browser component or a native component (e.g. Maps) as the first screen ever shown of your app and if you do you need to provide your own splash screens.

E.g.:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    if(!BrowserComponent.isNativeBrowserSupported()) {
        Form loading = new Form("Loading");
        loading.show();
    } else {
        Form hi = new Form("Test Browser");
        hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
        browser.setURL("https://www.codenameone.com/");
        hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
        hi.show();         
    }
}
```